# Is there a list of all the free ebooks available on Amazon?

Tags: amazon

Is there anywhere where I can search for and find a list of *all* the free ebooks on Amazon?

For example, I came across this interesting ebook about blockchain by chance and it is free: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B073YFZQDN/ref=oh_aui_d_detailpage_o00_?ie=UTF8&psc=1.

I'm interested to see if there are any other free ebooks I can get from Amazon. I have searched for this but have not been able to find any list / table that I can query.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Hundred Zeros website](http://hundredzeros.com/) - http://hundredzeros.com/?s=blockchain

It possibly built using Amazon's Products API